# Using ArcPy update cursor to replace <Null> value?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, cursor

I have been combing the help associated with  (None) values in arc, and have not been able to solve the following problem:

I have a a field with mixed Null and integer values:

0

100

I would like to transform the null values to 0's in python:

```
   cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fishJoin, ['myField']):

    for row in cursor:
        if row is None:
            row = 0
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This does not alter any of the null values.

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend using the [data access module](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000008000000) `da` with the [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//018v00000064000000) as you will notice significant performance improvements.  The following is the correct syntax to replace `<Null>` (aka `None`) values with 0.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\FGDB.gdb\andFC'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["Field_Name"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None:
            row[0] = 0
            cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"
```

---

The following is the correct syntax for ArcGIS 10.0 (i.e. without the `da` module).

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\FGDB.gdb\andFC'

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    if row.YourFieldName == None:
        row.YourFieldName = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"

del row
```

Comment: This script runs for me but does not end up changing the attribute.  My attribute is not a <Null> value but rather empty (i.e. '')  It prints "Processing Complete" but does not updated the value.  Here is my code:
`import arcpy

fc = r'D:\_data\sidewalk.gdb\repairs'

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    if row.FixedBy == None:
        row.YourFieldName = 'Contractor'
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"

del row`

Comment: @cbunn I would urge you to open a new question. It is difficult to understand your code in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, it is its own question now here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243256/update-cursor-script-not-running