# What is the most efficient way to search a geodatabase for NULL-like records?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, attribute-table

The problem: I have a geodatabase with several datasets and many more feature classes within.  The fields within the feature classes have been populated through joins with shapefiles and manual edits.  Often times string fields will become populated with whitespace (i.e. '', ' ', '   ', etc) or the string "Null", and numeric fields will become populated with a zero (0).  I would like to find these records and replace them with a true NULL value.  I have the following code, which uses an UpdateCursor, but it still very slow and doesn't catch all of the NULL-like records.  Does anyone know of other ways to accomplish this task?

```
GDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = GDB
datasetList = arcpy.ListDatasets() #list datasets

for dataset in datasetList:
        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(GDB, dataset)
        fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        for fc in fcList:
                arcpy.AddMessage("Processing %s..." % fc)
                #count features
                arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc, "tempTableView")
                count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("tempTableView").getOutput(0))
                if count > 0:
                        fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
                        for field in fieldList:
                                arcpy.AddMessage("...%s" % field.name)
                                rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
                                for row in rows:
                                        count = 0
                                        if row.isNull(field.name):
                                                continue # if already null
                                        elif field.type == "Text":
                                                value = row.getValue(field.name)
                                                if value.lstrip(' ') == '' or value.lower() == '<null>': # looks for whitespace or '<null>'
                                                        row.setNull(field.name)
                                                        count += 1
                                        elif field.type == "ShortInteger" or field.type == "LongInteger" or field.type == "Float" or field.type == "Double":
                                                value = row.getValue(field.name)
                                                if value == 0:
                                                        row.setNull(field.name)
                                                        count += 1
                                        if count > 0: # update row if records have changed
                                                rows.updateRow(row)
                                del rows
                else:
                        arcpy.AddMessage("...NO RECORDS FOUND.")
```

Comment: What version of arcgis do you have?

Comment: So, you have both 10.0 & 10.1?

Comment: I have access to both, yes.  Looking for a solution that will work for either or both.

Comment: Have you looked at this question here ? You could implement the 10 or 10.1 code into yours http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89362/using-arc-10-0-update-cursor-to-replace-null-value

Comment: Is this a personal (mdb), file (gdb), or RDBMS (ArcSDE)?

Comment: @RyanDalton, it is a versioned GDB from an SDE.

Comment: I just realized that I should mention that my database may contain features in a geometric network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I'm most familiar with 10.1+, and cursors in general are a lot better in the `da` module, here's a potential solution. Currently, you are creating a cursor each time you change fields, which means you are taking a hit there. Furthermore, you are checking the field type for each record instead of just using the field type once to filter initially.

I've changed how `Null` values are checked, but I haven't thoroughly tested it to check for all possible values. For the small sample dataset I had, it worked @ 10.2.2.

```
#Return None if the value needs to be changed, else return the value
def nullify(value):
    x = value    
    if value is not None: #True null fields are read as None types
        if type(value) == str:
            if value.lstrip(' ') == '' or value.lower() == '<null>':
                x = None
        else: 
            if value == 0:
                x = None 

return x
```

---

```
#We're only interested in some fields
ftypes = ("String", "SmallInteger", "Integer", "Double")
fieldList = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.type in ftypes]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldList) as rows:
    for row in rows:            
        nulled = map(nullify, row)
        if row != nulled: #Only update if the row actually needs to be changed.
            rows.updateRow(nulled)
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul, I like what you've done.  I too prefer the da module.  However, colleagues that share my workflow only have access to 10.0.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I get the following error `Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session` on `vals = [r for r in row]`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Barbarossa, I'm not sure; I've never come across that error before. Do the fields allow `Null` values? I've changed my code slightly there, but it should be the same.

Comment: I adjusted with `if f.isNullable == True` for the fieldList variable to eliminate not nullable fields.  I have found that the error may be due to the presence of a geometric network.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a cursor to look at all fields for each record (one at a time using the cursor), what about querying all records from a single field (in bulk) using "Select By Attributes" tool and then calculate all of the selected records using "Calculate Field" tool?  Then you could just loop over each field in Python?

Using your code as a base, I mocked up this (which works on a File GDB.  You'll have to correct the field syntax per database type based upon [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000).  I left some testing statements and the CalculateField statement commented out so you could test it out before actually breaking something.

I also borrowed the code to get your featureclasses from @gotchula answer to [Listing all feature classes in File Geodatabase, including within feature datasets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase)

```
import arcpy
import os

GDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = GDB

def listFcsInGDB():
    ''' set your arcpy.env.workspace to a gdb before calling '''
    #https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5893/listing-all-feature-classes-in-file-geodatabase-including-within-feature-datase
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            yield os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fds, fc)

fcList = listFcsInGDB()

for fc in fcList:
    arcpy.AddMessage("Processing %s..." % fc)
    #count features
    tempTableView = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc, "tempTableView")
    count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("tempTableView").getOutput(0))
    if count > 0:
        fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
        for field in fieldList:
            arcpy.AddMessage("...{0} ({1})".format(field.name, field.type) )
            if field.type == "Text" or field.type == "String":
                whereclause = "\"{0}\" = '' or \"{0}\" = ' ' or \"{0}\" = '  ' or \"{0}\" is NULL".format(field.name)
                #arcpy.AddMessage("Searching for " +field.name+ " where " +whereclause)
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tempTableView", "NEW_SELECTION", whereclause)
                #featcount = str(arcpy.GetCount_management("tempTableView").getOutput(0))
                #arcpy.AddMessage(featcount)
                #arcpy.CalculateField_management(tempTableView,"{0}".format(field.name), "NULL")
                count += 1
            elif field.type == "Integer" or field.type == "ShortInteger" or field.type == "SmallInteger" or field.type == "LongInteger" or field.type == "Short" or field.type == "Long" or field.type == "Float" or field.type == "Single" or field.type == "Double" or field.type == "Numeric":
                whereclause = "\"{0}\" = 0 or \"{0}\" is NULL".format(field.name)
                #arcpy.AddMessage("Searching for " +field.name+ " where " +whereclause)
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tempTableView", "NEW_SELECTION", whereclause)
                #featcount = str(arcpy.GetCount_management("tempTableView").getOutput(0))
                #arcpy.AddMessage(featcount)
                #arcpy.CalculateField_management(tempTableView,"{0}".format(field.name), "0")
                count += 1
            else:
                ##Not an editable field
                arcpy.AddMessage("Not an editable field type of: " + field.type)
                pass
```

Comment: Your answer actually resembles my original code, which ran slower than I would have liked.  Knowing that cursors are way faster than field calculator, I was hoping to use cursors.  However, if I cannot figure out how to implement them, I will happily accept your answer, as it works in both 10.0 and 10.1, as well as on various types of geodatabases.

Comment: @Barbarossa, You say using select & calculate is slower than cursoring through all records and updating individual columns per row?  I hope you share your benchmark statistics after you complete the two code options because that would surprise me, especially on larger datasets.

Comment: I have usually seen speed gains using cursors on my smaller databases, however I stand corrected.  After trying all 3 methods I have the following times: 1) arcpy.UpdateCursor - 1hr35m55s, 2) Select Layer and Calculate field - 34m36s, 3) arcpy.da.UpdateCursor - 1m40s.  I expected the da.UpdateCursor to be much faster, but it requires an edit session on my geometric network.

Comment: @Barbarossa, is that 1m40s for arcpy.da.UpdateCursor correct?  If so, wow, that's much faster than the others!

Comment: Yes it's correct.  Look [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/65515) for another example.