# Search and Update Cursor Automation: Avoid <Null> Values and Recognize Data Values

Tags: arcpy, cursor, update, search, attribute-joins

I am attempting to Search Cursor through a joined table. 
(I do not have access to the original separated tables)

If the value of "COMPANY" and "DATE_" are  then they will be skipped and it is suppose to pull the values from "COLLECTED_" (aka company) and "COLLECTION" (aka Date).  Unfortunately it proceeding to overwrite the values with Null.

## TOP:     New Table of Result

## BOTTOM:  Original Joined Table of Data

[image]

```
import arcpy as ARCPY
from arcpy import env as ENV
#Environment(s)
workspaceTEST = r"C:\Users\Jim\Desktop\TESTSTRM_SWR.gdb"
ENV.workspace = workspaceTEST

#Variables
pipes15096 = workspaceTEST + "\PIPES_15096"
pipesOfficial = workspaceTEST + "\OFFICIAL_PIPES2015"
fieldsPipesOfficial = ["ID_NUMBER", "DATE_","COMPANY","COLLECTION","COLLECTED_"]
```

## First Attempt:

```
valueDictOfficialPipes = {pipesRow[0]:(pipesRow[1:]) for pipesRow in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(pipesOfficial, fieldsPipesOfficial)}
fieldsPipes15096 = ["ID"  , "COLLECTION_DATE" , "COLLECTED_BY"]
with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(pipes15096, fieldsPipes15096) as updateRows_Pipes15096:  
    for updateRow2 in updateRows_Pipes15096:  
        keyValue2 = updateRow2[0]
        print "keyValue2:             ", keyValue2
        print "updateRow2:            ", updateRow2        
        if keyValue2 in valueDictOfficialPipes:  
            print "keyValue2 -V2:         ", keyValue2

            if valueDictOfficialPipes[1] and valueDictOfficialPipes[3] != ("<Null>" or " "):
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            updateRows_Pipes15096.updateRow(updateRow2)
            print "updateRow2:  ",updateRow2
del valueDictOfficialPipes
```

## I attempted to split into to separate dictionaries and ran them, but the result was cause the second dictionary to overwrite the correction by the first.

```
#replace fieldsPipesOfficial with the following:    
fieldsPipesOfficial_1 = ["ID_NUMBER", "DATE_",      "COMPANY",]
#                        (ID)         (DATE)       (Collected By)     
fieldsPipesOfficial_2 = ["ID_NUMBER", "COLLECTION","COLLECTED_"]
```

## Second Attempt

```
valueDictOfficialPipes_1 = {pipesRow[0]:(pipesRow[1:]) for pipesRow in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(pipesOfficial, fieldsPipesOfficial_1)}
fieldsPipes15096 = ["ID"  , "COLLECTION_DATE" , "COLLECTED_BY"]
with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(pipes15096, fieldsPipes15096) as updateRows_Pipes15096:  
    for updateRow2 in updateRows_Pipes15096:  
        keyValue2 = updateRow2[0]
        print "keyValue2:             ", keyValue2
        print "updateRow2:            ", updateRow2        
        if keyValue2 in valueDictOfficialPipes_1:  
            print "keyValue2 -V2:         ", keyValue2

            if valueDictOfficialPipes_1[1] == ("<null>" or " "):
                print "THERE SHOULD BE NO CHANGE"           
            else:
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes_1[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            updateRows_Pipes15096.updateRow(updateRow2)
            print "updateRow2:  ",updateRow2
```

## ====================================

```
valueDictOfficialPipes_2 = {pipesRow[0]:(pipesRow[1:]) for pipesRow in ARCPY.da.SearchCursor(pipesOfficial, fieldsPipesOfficial_2)}
fieldsPipes15096 = ["ID"  , "COLLECTION_DATE" , "COLLECTED_BY"]
with ARCPY.da.UpdateCursor(pipes15096, fieldsPipes15096) as updateRows_Pipes15096:  
    for updateRow2 in updateRows_Pipes15096:  
        keyValue2 = updateRow2[0]
        print "keyValue2:             ", keyValue2
        print "updateRow2:            ", updateRow2        
        if keyValue2 in valueDictOfficialPipes_2:  
            print "keyValue2 -V2:         ", keyValue2
            if valueDictOfficialPipes_2[1] == ("<null>" or " "):
                print "THERE SHOULD BE NO CHANGE"           
            else:
                for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                    updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes_2[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                    print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            updateRows_Pipes15096.updateRow(updateRow2)
            print "updateRow2:  ",updateRow2

del valueDictOfficialPipes_1
del valueDictOfficialPipes_2
```

Comment: You cannot pick Null values by comparing them to "<Null>" . http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110309/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-search-a-geodatabase-for-null-like-records

Answer (score 2):

If these are true Null fields and not strings with the word `"<Null>"`, then you need to use *None* in Python for Null.  Try:

```
        if valueDictOfficialPipes_2[1] in [None, "", " "]:
            for nullNoMore in range (1,len(fieldsPipes15096)): 
                updateRow2[nullNoMore] = valueDictOfficialPipes_2[keyValue2][nullNoMore-1]  
                print "updateRow2[nullNoMore]:  ",updateRow2[nullNoMore]
            updateRows_Pipes15096.updateRow(updateRow2)
```

Edit: I extended the code to show how you have to write this section to make only records that have no value be overwritten and ignore all other rows.  The updateRow method should only run if a row is actually updated, so it only runs if the if clause is true.

Comment: I'd also include an empty string `""` as these are not `Null`.

Comment: I added "" to the list.

Comment: Richard,
  Thank you that helps, but it is still overwriting the values with <Null> values.  
I am attempting to make it recognize that if there is any values other than [None, "", " "] then it should ignore/skip that row and only replace the rows which contain a [None, "", " "]

Comment: Then you wrote your code logic in reverse, since what you wrote will ignore all rows with [None, "", " "] and overwrite all other rows.  Don't include any else clause with this if statement and just do the overwrite code you have written if it is true.  indent your updateRow method one level since it only needs to run if the clause is true.