# Update Cursor Script Not Running

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I have a script I want to use to update a value for a group of selected features in ArcMap in a string field.  I am using the UpdateCursor method but I cannot get the output generated that I want.  I know my code is close but something is off.  Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'D:\_data\sidewalk.gdb\repairs'

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

for row in cursor:
    if row.FixedBy == '':
        row.FixedBy = 'Contractor'
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "Processing complete"

del row
```

I am trying to update the string "FixedBy" field where values are blank, not 'Null', with the value 'Contractor'.  What is my code missing?

Comment: `cursor.updateRow(row)` should be unindented. Try replacing `row.FixedBy == ''` with `row.FixedBy == None`. Also, I would recommend using the new data access `da` cursors.

Comment: I get a syntax error when i unindent curcor.updateRow(row).  Any my originaly value is not Null but rather blank.

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement within your cursor to see what the true value is of your `row`.

Comment: Would you mind providing a full answer, then I can mark it as correct if it runs.

Comment: Using CalculateField_management might be an easier approach

Comment: I have several values that I need to update so it would be much easier to run a script than to do it in the field calculator.  That is what I am currently doing.

Comment: Shouldn't `row.YourFieldName = 'Contractor'` be `row.FixedBy = 'Contractor'` if you are trying to update this field?

Comment: Yes it should, I must have copied the wrong code snippet for the questiont.  I had been running it with the correct field name there though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if the value of FixedBy is NULL or blank (meaning no text at all, including spaces):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'D:\_data\sidewalk.gdb\repairs'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['FixedBy']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == None or row[0] == '':
            row[0] = 'Contractor'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This runs perfectly thank you!  If the GDB is stored on an SDE server what would the file path look like?

Comment: Glad it helped. You could look at this answer to know how to do that. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5541/9518.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to pass in a where clause to the UpdateCursor; then you don't need to check any values.  All rows returned could be updated.

Assuming you are using 10.1+, switching to arcpy.da cursors is also recommended.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'D:\_data\sidewalk.gdb\repairs'
i = 0

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['FixedBy'], "FixedBy =''") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 'Contractor'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        i += 1

print "Processed {}...".format(i)
```

(Untested code.)

If the count is 0, there is a problem with your where clause or your data isn't what you think you are seeing.

Comment: OP mentioned in the comments that other edits were also being made in the cursor loop, so the where clause may not be appropriate in this specific case.

Comment: It says it processed all the records despite me only selecting 2 records for it to run against.  Also it did not update the "FixedBy" field.  It is a string field in a File GDB.  How do I adjust my where clause?

Comment: @cbunn Try `"\"FixedBy\" = ''"` as your where clause